# AVPlayer and AVPlayerItem - Determining if an NSError is Fatal

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayeritem, core-media

Is there a way to determine whether an NSError thrown via notifications is a fatal error (that ends/prevents video playback), as opposed to non-fatal (e.g. sound missing, but playback resumes)?

We've previously relied on player.rate being 0 (to indicate the player was unable to start) to determine if the error was fatal, but this is proving to be unreliable.